# WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_CONTAINER_URL is a hidden application setting?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When swapping slots we get the following message:

[image]

But the WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_CONTAINER_URL setting does not exist in the Application Settings of either web app. I understand that it comes from enabling Web App Diagnostics Logs, but it is somehow hidden.

The issue is that this will cause an IIS restart in the production slot, and thus downtime until it has completed all initialisation tasks. There is no way to configure this settings as a "Slot Setting" (which would prevent an edit to the application settings).

The odd thing is that DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL is visible in application settings (it is also a Diagnostics Log configuration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_CONTAINER_URL is a hidden application setting?

In short answer: Yes. This is a hidden app setting which is used to store the web server log's blob container url.

After you have enabled the web server logging in the diagnostics logs, it will add your storage container url in the app setting. You couldn't change it in the application settings.

In my opinion, I think this value must be changed when swap the web app. Since the production slot could set its own web server logging storage container. If this not changed, you log information may be changed the blob container.

You could find it in the KUDU console's environment variables as below.

Open the kudu.

[image]

Then click the environment and find the Environment variables.

[image]

---

Update:

> The problem is that changing application settings will perform an IIS reset, which will bring down the production slot.

As far as I know, the swap operation will not cause an IIS restart in the production slot. It will automatic warm up in the staging slot before swap to the production slot.

The swap operation is as below:

1.The App Settings and Connection Strings that are marked as “Slot” are read from the Production slot and applied to the site in the Staging slot. That causes the site’s worker process to be restarted for those changes to take effect and become visible as process environment variables;

2.Then the site in the staging slot gets warmed up. To warm up the site an HTTP request is made to the root directory of the site to every VM instance where site is supposed to run. The warm up request has a User-Agent header set to “SiteWarmup”;

3.After warm up has completed the host names for the sites in production and staging slots get swapped. Now the site that has been warmed up in the staging slot starts getting production traffic and the site that used to be in the production slot is now in the staging slot

4.The site that is now in the staging slot gets updated with the App Settings and Connection Strings associated with the staging slot. That causes restart of that site, but it is not in production slot any more so restart is harmless.

But sometimes it would be useful to pause right after the production settings were applied on the staging slot and before the actual swap of host names happens.

Now, azure web app has another swap: [swap with preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-staged-publishing#swap-with-preview-multi-phase-swap).

When you use the Swap with preview option, App Service does the following:

1.Keeps the destination slot unchanged so existing workload on that slot (e.g. production) is not impacted.

2.Applies the configuration elements of the destination slot to the source slot, including the slot-specific connection strings and app settings.
Restarts the worker processes on the source slot using these aforementioned configuration elements.

3.When you complete the swap: Moves the pre-warmed-up source slot into the destination slot. The destination slot is moved into the source slot as in a manual swap.

4.When you cancel the swap: Reapplies the configuration elements of the source slot to the source slot.

You can preview exactly how the app will behave with the destination slot's configuration. Once you completes validation, you complete the swap in a separate step. This step has the added advantage that the source slot is already warmed up with the desired configuration, and clients will not experience any downtime.

You could find it as below:

[image]

Comment: The problem is that changing application settings will perform an IIS reset, which will bring down the production slot. This defeats the point of the blue-green swap.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation - all makes sense.